# Generated field = generated $\sigma$-field when generating family (of sets) is finite

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A$ be a finite family of subsets of the space $\Omega$ (with, say, $n$ elements), and denote $A^c$ as the family of subsets that are complimentary to each of the subsets in $A$ (also containing $n$ elements).

I am attempting to prove that the $\sigma$-field generated by $A$, denoted $\sigma(A)$ is contained in the field generated by $A$, denoted $f(A)$, given that $A$ is finite. While this seems intuitively obvious, I'm struggling to formalize the fact that any countable union of elements would have to be a finite union of elements because $A$ and $A^c$ are each finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a finite field $\{A_1,A_2,...,A_n\}$. Consider any sequence $(B_k)$ in this field. Consider $\cup_k B_k$. Let $\{C_1,C_2,...,C_N\}$ denote those $A_i$'s that appear in the collection $\{B_k: k \geq 1\}$. This is a finite collection from the field. You can easily verify that $\cup_k B_k =\cup_i C_i$ by showing that each side is contained in the other. We have shown that any countable union of sets from the field can be expressed as   finite union of set from the field.